# Random versioning number with images to force cache

Tags: php, javascript, html, random, version

I few random php scripts with various parts of HTML code in them, stylesheets and images. But lately I'm having a problem with cache.

I add a random versioning number to stylesheet to force it to be a new stylesheet.

```
    <script>document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/fonts/rotate.php?dev=' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + '" type="text/css" media="screen" />');</script>
```

How can do something similar with the images?

```
<script>
document.write("<IMG SRC=" + "/images/rotate.php" + ">");

</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with `"/images/rotate.php?dev=" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)`?

Comment: Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @Explosion Pills: nothing, but it's extremely hard to figure it out when you can do nothing but copy-paste code

Comment: @Explosion Pills could you please give me an example?

Comment: I don't believe you can only copy-paste. OP can look, learn and apply. @uriah, he just did!

Comment: random !== random. It will repeat, use a timestamp!

Comment: @zerkms I noticed that but I was ambiguous. Fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add the following headers to **rotate.php**:

```
  header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
  header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT"); 
  header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"); 
  header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false); 
  header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

You can also try via the .htaccess file:

```
<Directory />
    <filesMatch "rotate.(html|htm|js|css|php)$">
    FileETag None
    <ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset ETag
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
    </ifModule>
    </filesMatch>
</Directory>
```

Comment: Not the method the user wanted but +1 for a sensible answer

Comment: And again, Jul 26th, what's wrong with this date?! http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/164696/18348

Comment: awesome date dont you think so? :D

Comment: Took me a while to work out how to edit the php file and where to put the headers but I got it, thanks heaps @Eldar

Answer (score -3):

You can add random gibberish parameters at the end.

```
"/images/rotate.php?dev=" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 101)
```

Comment: apparently i misunderstood

Comment: No, you just posted conjecture as an answer

Comment: I removed I think, now its not conjecture.

Comment: Ok. Now it's a comment. If you were to provide example code it may be an answer! And that -3 might disappear.

Comment: this is still low quality because you don't give an example (and the OP is in the place because they need an improved sense of best practices).

Comment: OP provided valid code. What he is doing should work for images.

Comment: Though headers is a better method.

Comment: However stealing from Explosion Pills is bad m'kay.